# Perl sendmail attach log files match date format

Tags: bash, sendmail, perl, mime, attachment

I want to send log files matching date format, e.g. YYYY-MM-DD-*.log as attachments in Perl script. In BASH, this can be easily done by:

```
[ -f $DIR/explog/$(date "+%Y-%m-%d")-*-host1.log ] && mutt -s "subject here" \
-a $DIR/explog/$(date "+%Y-%m-%d")-*-host1.log my@email.com </dev/null
```

For some reason, I need to do this in Perl script. Main part of the Perl script is as below, I want to add log files in the emails. Any idea?

BTW, this Perl script is called as a email alert from BASH shell script, so if there is any method to pass files to perl script e.g. */usr/bin/perl $DIR/emailAlert.pl file1.log file2.log* would serve the purpose. Please advise, thanks.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use MIME::Lite;

$msg = MIME::Lite->new( 
    From => 'sender\@example.com', 
    To => 'recipient\@example.com', 
    Subject => 'subject here', 
    Type => 'multipart/mixed'
); 

$msg->attach(
    Type    => "text/plain",
    Path    => $tmpMsg,
    Filename    => $tmpMsg,
    Disposition => "attachment"
);

$msg->send('smtp', 'mailserver.example.com', Timeout => 60);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use arguments in statements like `$log1 = $ARGV[0]` and `$log2 = $ARGV[1]` and assign them in your `$msg->attach` section.
You can use it like this:

```
    while (@ARGV) {  
        $msg->attach(  
            'Type' => 'text/plain',  
            'Path' => shift @ARGV
        );  
    }
```

Comment: Great! Exactly what I want.